# After checked values is not getting unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery

My requirement is once I click on checkbox and save/update textbox should be disabled and when I uncheck and save/update textbox should be enabled. During check `latest_file` value should be `1` and during uncheck its value should be `0`. Here is my code which I tried:

```
function disableFileName() {
    var latestFile = $("#latestFile").is(":checked");
    if (latestFile) {
        $("#fileName").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    } else {
        $("#fileName").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Process the latest file from the feed location  </td>
        <td>
            <s:checkbox property="latestFile" styleId="latestFile" value="1" onclick="disableFileName();" tabindex="5" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>File Name</td>
        <td nowrap="true">
            <s:text property="fileName" styleClass="textbox" styleId="fileName" style="{width:150}" tabindex="6" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Use `prop`. `$("#fileName").prop('disabled', true/false)`

Comment: Sorry Tushar but I dint get you.... :(

Comment: Use `prop()` method instead of `attr()` and `removeAttr()`. Second param `true` will disable the input and `false` will enable it.

Comment: `style="{width:150}"` does not appear to be valid `html` for `style` attribute?

Comment: if (latestFile) {
       prop. $("#fileName").prop('disabled', true/false)
    } else {
        $("#fileName").prop("disabled");
    }  You mean this???

Comment: @Tushar `javascript` at Question returns expected result. Is `disableFileName` defined? Are `styleId="latestFile"` and `styleId="fileName"` converted to `id` at server or portions of `js` which do not appear at Question?

Answer (score 0):

`javascript` at Question returns expected result where `disableFileName`, `#latestFile`, `#fileName` are defined. To toggle `value` of `#latestFile` you can use `$("#latestFile").val(1);` at `if`, `$("#latestFile").val(1);` at `else`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function disableFileName() {
  
    var latestFile = $("#latestFile").is(":checked");
    if (latestFile) {
        $("#latestFile").val(1);
        $("#fileName").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    } else {
       $("#latestFile").val(0);
        $("#fileName").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    console.log($("#latestFile").val());
}
</script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Process the latest file from the feed location</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" property="latestFile" id="latestFile" value="1" onclick="disableFileName();" tabindex="5" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>File Name</td>
    <td nowrap="true">
      <input type="text" property="fileName" class="textbox" id="fileName" style="width:150" tabindex="6" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `prop` instead of `attr` to disable the checkbox as shown below:

```
$("#fileName").prop("disabled", "true");
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Process the latest file from the feed location  </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="latestFile" value="1" onclick="disableFileName();" tabindex="5" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>File Name</td>
        <td nowrap="true">
            <input type="textbox" name="fileName" styleClass="textbox" id="fileName" style="width:150" tabindex="6" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
function disableFileName() {
    var latestFile = $("#latestFile").is(":checked");
    if (latestFile) {
        $("#fileName").prop("disabled", "true");
        $("#latestFile").attr("value", "1");
    } else {
        $("#fileName").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#latestFile").attr("value", "0");
    }
}
```

Here is the demo: [JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/591bnk91/12/)

Comment: What is issue with `javascript` at Question which uses `.attr()`, `.removeAttr()` ? See also OP at _"During check `latest_file` value should be `1` and during uncheck its value should be `0`."_

Comment: _"Try using prop instead of attr to disable the checkbox"_ Use of `.attr()`, `.removeAttr()` at Question returns expected result, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/39286580/; `.prop()` should return same result as `javascript` at Question. The issue is `#latestFile`, `#fileName` do not appear to be defined at `html`; not certain if `disableFileName` is defined before being called